# BIRT parameters getting rounded

Tags: sql-server, birt

I am migrating BIRT reports from version 2.6 to 4.4 and facing a very strange issue which is as under

BIRT parameter passed as part of the query gets rounded off i.e if I pass 1 as parameter, query gets executed for 0 and if I pass parameter as 99 or 101, the query gets executed for 100

Query - select data from table1 where actualID = ?;

The datatype for parameter is Decimal (28,0)

DB used is SQL Server 2012

I have logged the value of parameter in BIRT Functions (beforeOpen, beforeClose and others) and it always show the parameter value consistent with what I have passed.

Please help me understand or point me to a direction where I can take this investigation further

Any help will be much appreciated

Note
If I convert datatype from Decimal to String, it works fine
If I pass parameter as part of Query it works fine but it doesn't work when parameter value dynamically replaces '?' in the query

Comment: possible duplicate of [BIRT 4.4.0 PARAMETERS getting rounded at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882302/birt-4-4-0-parameters-getting-rounded-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

You should also log the parameter values in the afterOpen event.
Maybe they are modified somehow in the beforeOpen event.
In my BIRT framework, I have defined a function like this:

```
afterOpen: function(ds) {
    log.debug("afterOpen DS " + ds.getName() + " inputParams=" + ds.getInputParameters().toString());
}
```

This function can be called as trace.afterOpen.
Then I can use it in the data set's afterOpen event like this:

```
trace.afterOpen(this);
```

You could also set BIRT's internal logging to FINEST; that will generate loads of debug messages and should include the bind variables for each SQL statement executed AFAIK.

Comment: I did the logging and value of parameter is reflected as the one which was passed to query and not the rounded value which is actually getting passed to DB
I logged value of parameters after various internal BIRT functions (though I am not sure about the order in which they are called) but value of parameter still remains the one which was sent as part of the query and not the rounded one