# BIRT 4.4.0 PARAMETERS getting rounded at runtime

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, birt

We have BIRT 4.4.0 report with a report parameter of decimal data type.
The report parameter gets rounded up/down to the nearest 10 in Data Set Preview Results (and when the report is run, but we've narrowed the problem to the Data Set).
E.g. if the paramter is 
0-4, rounds down to 0
5-9, rounds up to 10
10-14 rounds down to 10
15-20 rounds up to 20
:
:
90-94 rounds down to 90
95-100 rounds up to 100

The database is SQLServer 2012. The problem has not been tested against other databases.

The .rptdesign is not being included, since the various tests below change it and you can use a blank report.
The problem is in the DataSet and you won't need to run a report, but to preview results in the DataSet.

Steps to reproduce
1) Use BIRT 4.4.0 designer, Java 1.7 u25 (jdk-7u25-windows-i586.exe), SQLServer 2012

2)

```
Create a database (AlbumsDB) with a table (Albums) with the following columns
Title   varchar(50)  not null
Cost    decimal(18,0) not null
Type    char(10) not null
```

3)

```
Populate with the following 3 rows
   Title         Cost          Type
   APPLE          0               D
   ABBEY ROAD     1               D
   BEATLES        2               D
```

4) Create a blank report
5) Create a Datasource to the SQLServer
6) Create a Dataset

The Data Set query in BIRT is created using column selection from the table (and not typed in).
Please keep the format exactly as shown, using only cursor positioning and double-clicking the column/table names to select them.

```
select dbo.Albums.Title,
dbo.Albums.Cost,
dbo.Albums.type
from dbo.Albums
where dbo.Albums.Cost = ?
```

The query parameter:

```
Name: param_1
Native Name: greyed out and not enterable
Data Type: Decimal
Direction: Input
Default Value: 2
Linked to Report Parameter: None
```

The default parameter was set to 2, so that tests will either produce the correct Cost=2 row, or round down and produce the incorrect Cost=0 row.

## Tests

1) When the SQL statement was setup in this format, 
- the "Preview Results' in the Data Set produced the wrong result  (the rounded down Cost=0 row)
- the .rptdesign file did not have the nativeDataType attribute

2) When sql was edited and the table name was brought up to the same line as the last column selected as:

```
select dbo.Albums.Title,
dbo.Albums.Cost,
dbo.Albums.type from dbo.Albums
where dbo.Albums.Cost = ?
```

- the "Peview Results " in the Data Set produced the correct result (the Cost=2 row)
- the .rptdesign file did not have the nativeDataType attribute

3) When the format of the sql was

```
select dbo.Albums.Title, dbo.Albums.Cost,
dbo.Albums.type 
from dbo.Albums
where dbo.Albums.Cost = ?
```

or

```
select dbo.Albums.Title,.Albums.Cost,.Albums.type 
from dbo.Albums
where dbo.Albums.Cost = ?
```

that is, some or all columns selected put on same line as "select",  keeping "from " on a separate line
- the "Preview Results' in the Data Set produced the wrong result  (the rounded down Cost=0 row)
- the .rptdesign file did not have the nativeDataType attribute

4) When the entire SQL was put on one line

```
select dbo.Albums.Title,.Albums.Cost,.Albums.type from dbo.Albums where dbo.Albums.Cost = ?
- the "Peview Results " in the Data Set produced the correct result  (the Cost=2 row)
- the .rptdesign file now had the correct  nativeDataType attribute `<propert name="nativeDataType">3</property>`
```

5) When any whitespace (spaces)  was introduced in the statement:

```
select                dbo.Albums.Title,
dbo.Albums.Cost,
dbo.Albums.type
from dbo.Albums
where dbo.Albums.Cost = ?
- the "Preview Results' in the Data Set produced the wrong result  (the rounded down Cost=0 row)
- the .rptdesign file had an incorrect nativeDataType attribute `<property name="nativeDataType">0</property>`
```

In all tests above, if the SQL format was reverted, the nativeDataType attribute stayed in the .rptdesign file.
It got changed from "0" to "3" when the "from dbo.Albums" was brought upto the same line as "select".

6) Adding the nativeDataType  line to the .rptdesign had no effect, until step 6d)
a) Edited the initial .rptdesign (without the nativeDataType) and with the sql format as created in #1, and added `<property name="nativeDataType">3</property>` 
- the "Preview Results' in the Data Set produced the wrong result  (the rounded down Cost=0 row)
b) Then added `<property name="nativeName"></property>`
- the "Preview Results' in the Data Set produced the wrong result  (the rounded down Cost=0 row)

c) Then added `<property name="isOptional">false</property>`
- the "Preview Results' in the Data Set produced the wrong result  (the rounded down Cost=0 row)

d) When a slight change to the format of the SQL statement is made (bring the "from db.Albums" up to the line of the last column selected), CDReport.rptdesign produces the correct result.

Comment: Does it change anything if you set the type of the query parameter to "Float" or "Integer" through Eclipse designer? Otherwise, please create a report parameter and link it to the query parameter. Take care the datatype of the report parameter should be the same as the query parameter. Try to change the value of the report parameter through parameters box of your Eclipse designer, and let us know if this is changing a thing.

Comment: changing both the query and report parameters to Integer had no effect on adding the nativeDataType or producing the correct result

Answer (score 0):

If the results is depending on the SQL statements's format (different results although the semantics of the statements are the same), as you mention in d), then this is definitely a bug, either in BIRT 4.4.1 or in the JDBC driver (or in SQL Server, but I don't think so).

To see where the bug is actually happening you should

- Test the same report with BIRT 4.2.1
- Test the SQL statement (exactly the same statement, using bind vars!) in some SQL-JDBC IDE (for Oracle, this would be SQL Developer, I don't know if something similar is available for MS SQL Server) or, lacking such an IDE, in a stand-alone Java program.
- Test the same report with a different JDBC driver